# How do I create an AVD which replicates the Dell Streak's display

Tags: android

Is there a guide somewhere showing [Device] > [Settings to replicate it in AVD]??  If not, what values should I use for the Dell Streak specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I do not own a Dell Streak but, with reference to [this](http://www.gsmarena.com/dell_streak-3353.php) I would advise you to use a 480*800 pixels screen.